# How do you pivot data from a list of data frames in R?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a list of data frames ldf:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c(1,2), value = c(4,5))
df2 <- data.frame(date = c(1,2), value = c(4,5))
ldf <- list(df1, df2)
```

What is the best way to get the sum (or any other function) of values by date, i.e. some data frame like:

```
data.frame(date = c(1,2), value = c(8,10))
```

Comment: `rbindlist` in the data.table package is very fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- rbindlist(ldf)
setkey(dt1,'date')
dt1[,list(value=sum(value)), by='date']
 date value
1:    1     8
2:    2    10
```

Answer (score 1):

If these rows were all in the same data frame, you would use `aggregate` to do the sum.  You can combine them with `rbind` so they are in the same data frame:

```
aggregate(value ~ date, data=do.call(rbind, ldf), FUN=sum)
  date value
1    1     8
2    2    10
```

If the `date` columns in all the data frames are identical, you can easily use `Reduce` to do the sum:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) data.frame(date=x$date, value=x$value+y$value), ldf)
  date value
1    1     8
2    2    10
```

This should be a lot faster than `rbind`-ing the data together and aggregating.

Comment: is this still an efficient solution if there are thousands of data frames rather than just 2?

Comment: `rbind` is not extremely efficient.  It would be better if you could read them into a single data frame.

Comment: thanks. my individual data frames are being returned by a function, rather than being read in directly. is there a different data structure that my function should return for efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `unnest` from "tidyr" in conjunction with the typical grouping and aggregation functions via "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

unnest(ldf) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
# 
#   date value
# 1    1     8
# 2    2    10
```